# How to vectorize dynamically sized numpy arrays in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, apply

Currently, I am using the `apply` method on my dataframe in order to create a computed column which contains lists of variable sizes (depending on the value in the `length` column).

Is there a way to create a column with variable-sized lists more efficiently with pandas?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [
                  6, 7, 8, 9, 0], 'length': [3, 5, 7, 9, 3]})
df['computed'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: np.array([x['a'], x['b']] + [x['b'] + i for i in range(1, x['length'] - 1)]), axis=1)
```

Desired output (works with code above, but slow):

```
   a  b  length                            computed
0  1  6       3                           [1, 6, 7]
1  2  7       5                    [2, 7, 8, 9, 10]
2  3  8       7           [3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
3  4  9       9  [4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
4  5  0       3                           [5, 0, 1]
```

Comment: I do not think we have better way for create list type column ..

Comment: Would they be all positive numbers in a and b?

Comment: @Divakar not necessarily. Would that make a difference? The length would be at least 2, because the pattern is [a, b, b+1, ..., b + length - 2].

Comment: When I see lists that vary in length, I think Python iteration, not "vectorization".  True `numpy` vectorization works with rectangular arrays, not ragged ones (or arrays of lists).

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
df['computed']= [[a]+[b]+list(np.arange(b+1, length)) for a, b, length in zip(df.a, df.b, (df.b) + df.length-1)]
```

o/P:

```
   a  b  length                            computed
0  1  6       3                           [1, 6, 7]
1  2  7       5                    [2, 7, 8, 9, 10]
2  3  8       7           [3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
3  4  9       9  [4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
4  5  0       3                           [5, 0, 1]
```

Comment: This works, but there is still a for loop which is what I was trying to avoid if possible. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's a list comprehension. It improves performance and better than for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for but, if it's too slow you can always try multiprocessing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def parallelize(df, func, n_cores=4):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, n_cores)
    pool = Pool(n_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df

def func(df):
    df['computed'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.array([x['a'], x['b']] + [x['b'] + i for i in range(1, x['length'] - 1)]), axis=1)
    return df

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [6, 7, 8, 9, 0], 'length': [3, 5, 7, 9, 3]})
df = parallelize(df, func)
```

(for small values of `length` it will be less efficient than your original code)